# Debug and Release apk not working in React Native 0.63.3

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, apk

[image]

I am using below steps to build debug and release apk

1. cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..
2. cd android && ./gradlew cleanBuildCache && cd ..
3. npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev true --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res --verbose
4. cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug && cd .. or cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease && cd ..

The apks are generated successfully. But when i run them i always got this.

However, If i start the metro-server the app works fine but not the debug-apk.

Any help will be appreciated.

Andoid config:

```
 buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
 minSdkVersion = 23
 compileSdkVersion = 29
 targetSdkVersion = 29

 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

Manifest

```
<application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    >
```

app's build.gradle

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
    devDisabledInDev: true, // Disable dev server in dev release
    bundleInDev: true, // add
    bundleInDebug: true
]
```

Thanks

Comment: run `npx react-native start` in project directory of your main terminal OR run `npm react-native run-android` in your VS after running `npx react-native start`.

Comment: I tried that as well, But when i generate the build and install that apk file i got the same error.

Comment: If you are running the app on a emulator then try like, `react-native run-android --variant=debug`

Comment: check this https://dev.to/nitish173/how-to-generate-a-debug-apk-in-react-native-1gdg

Comment: i am successfully able to generate the build, The problem is when i install it from storage, it gives me this error.

Answer (score 3):

In terminal of your project directory:-

`cd android`
then  `./gradlew clean`
then `cd ..`

then
//to create bundle
`npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/`

then
//to create debug build
`npx react-native run-android variant=debug`

and
//to create release build
`npx react-native run-android variant=release`

Note :- Make sure you have run `npm start` in project root directory before all.

Answer (score 0):

there are few steps below:

Goto project directory

//write into terminal

1. cd android.

//clean by writing this.

2=> ./gradlew clean

//come back to project directory

3. cd..

//write this complete code to the project directory

4. npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/

//write into terminal

5. cd android

//  if you want debug(.apk)

6=> ./gradlew assembleDebug

//  if you want in release mode(.apk)

6=> ./gradlew assembleRelease

//  if you want in Bundle release(.abb)

6=> ./gradle bundleRelease

7. finally find and share from below path.

// for debug

android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk

// for release

android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk

// for production

android/app/release/app-release.abb