# Why the release version of my app in react native fails to open when installed on a physical android device?

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, release

I have a problem installing the Release version of my application.

Before uploading my application to the playstore I wanted to test the debug and release version on my physical and virtual device that I generated with the following commands:

./gradlew assembleDebug

./gradlew assembleRelease

./gradlew bundleRelease

At the time of testing the debug version works correctly on my virtual and physical device using the following command:

npx react-native run-android --variant=debug

The problem starts when I want to test the release on my devices using the following command:

npx react-native run-android --variant=release

The application can be installed on the devices but it cannot be opened. I leave a screenshot of the messages that the console throws when testing the release version, it is worth mentioning that I generated the boundleRelease I uploaded it to the playstore and when I did a closed test, when I installed my app on my device the same thing happened, the Application is installed but cannot be opened.

When starting the execution of the command it shows this:

[console messages at startup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNb7V.png)

At the end of the execution of the command it shows this:

[console messages on completion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1AJm.png)

These are the specifications that I am using

[specifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH7uv.png)

I have tried this

there are few steps below:

Goto project directory

//write into terminal

cd android.
//clean by writing this.

2=> ./gradlew clean

//come back to project directory

cd..
//write this complete code to the project directory

npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
//write into terminal

cd android
// if you want debug(.apk)

6=> ./gradlew assembleDebug

// if you want in release mode(.apk)

6=> ./gradlew assembleRelease

// if you want in Bundle release(.abb)

6=> ./gradle bundleRelease

finally find and share from below path.
// for debug

android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk

// for release

android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk

// for production

android/app/release/app-release.abb

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71602677

https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!!!

Maybe it will help someone in the future. Based on this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33202 which has now been closed I had to update my project to the latest version of react-native available today (0.71.1 ) It is worth mentioning that I was using the version (0.70.6) and the update was done manually using the upgrade-helper: https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/ I share the official response that helped me to base myself on the solution: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33202#issuecomment-1411938054

With this solution I can already generate the release version, test it on my physical or virtual device and even generate the boundleRelease to be able to upload it to the PlayStore and do closed tests. It works correctly with my testers

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36023